# Standard library to_string(double) giving wrong value in vs2015 . Is there any solution?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, visual-studio-2015, stl

In Vs2013 to_string function std::to_string(1.0e+30) provides the output 1000000000000000000000000000000.000000

In Vs2015 to_string function std::to_string(1.0e+30) provides the output 1000000000000000019884624838656.000000

If it is with standard library issue is there any fix or patch available for it?

I searched for this problem and encountered an article explains https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/6xhWgsEuvPo 
to_string has bug in float or double convertion .

```
double d = 1.0000000000000000e+30;
std::string s = std::to_string(d);
if (s.length())
{
    s;
}
```

here s give value as 1000000000000000019884624838656.000000

Expected result is 1000000000000000000000000000000.000000 which gives in vs2013 but not in vs2015

Comment: have you tried sprintf_s(..) instead? does it give the same results?

Comment: Aside: what are you expecting `s;` to do?

Comment: it is also giving same output as 1000000000000000019884624838656.000000

Comment: the problem shown here is sample code

Comment: `s;` is a statement that **does nothing**. Are you sure it's not `std::cout << s;` or similar?

Comment: "What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic": https://floating-point-gui.de/  .. although your example is sort of special that you have only "integer-like" value, but it's still floating point value encoded as IEEE754, so you are just hitting limits of that numerical type in a bit "unhuman" way, but from computer point of view it's all correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the standard, *both* are "correct" results.

> There are three floating-point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`. The type `double` provides at least as much precision as `float`, and the type `long double` provides at least as much precision as `double`. The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`; the set of values of the type `double` is a subset of the set of values of the type `long double`. The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined. [ Note: This document imposes no requirements on the accuracy of floating-point operations; see also [`[support.limits]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.limits). — end note ]

The VS 2015 result is more common, as that conforms to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). With that definition,  `1000000000000000000000000000000` is not representable, the closest representable number to it is `1000000000000000019884624838656`.

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision.

I'm actually surprised as to how VS 2013 arrives at `1000000000000000000000000000000`. See [the examples at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [lexical_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.numbers_to_strings_conversion) from boost library to avoid this problem:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

double d = 1.0000000000000000e+30;
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(d);
std:: cout << s;
```

and the result on VS2015 is:

```
The value of s is: 1e+30
```

Comment: or just `std::cout << d;`, however this doesn't answer why the fixed point string isn't the number @sukumar thinks it should be

Comment: @Caleth I think the Q asks for some way to have the value of a BIG double into a string, not just printing it. The main reason of the error has been mentioned by you correctly. But this can also be a workaround to fix that issue in the code.